# Search data to calculate the quantity with VBA UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, search, userform

Its my first time using VBA and any sort of coding in general so I have been cracking my head for weeks trying to do this UserForm . I'm wondering if there is anyone here that could help me with it? Any help is appreciated, Thank you in advance!!

I've created a UserForm to key in data into the excel spreadsheet. There is Name, Product, Date and Quantity. I would like the last column to be Time Taken ( which is Quantity*standard time ) The Data for the standard time is in another sheet ( Sheet2 ) and to get the standard time, I would have to identify first from which group does the product lies, as the standard time is tied to the group. I am able to do it with excel formula ( IFS ) quite easily but I would like to do it with VBA so whoever uses it wouldn't accidentally delete or change the formula. Is there a way to do so? I'll attach the screenshot of the excel formula below.

The Excel formula that I would like to change to VBA and the reference sheet (Sheet2) that states the group and standard time

[The IFS formula that I want to change to VBA code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWQxz.png)

[The reference for the grouping and standard time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwqnW.png)

[UserForm to key in data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS6N1.png)

[Overview of the datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st9Wd.png)

Please let me know if there is any where I could explain better or if I lack any important details to the question.
And once again thank you for attempting/reading! I really appreciate it and would be grateful for any kind of help! Thank you!!

Comment: You have too many questions in 1 Post. You need to focus on 1 problem per post. I would recommend editing your question. Once your query is sorted, put up a 2nd post for the next query.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry I should've done that! Thank you for the suggestion, I'll edit the second question away now

Comment: You can use Find() to locate the Product in the products table, then use the found cell Column to reference the correct product group cell on row 3.  Use vlookup with the product group to get the corresponding time.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for your suggestion! I'm wondering if I can do this all with VBA userform instead? Because this sheet will be pass down to somebody else to use for all the months to come and with vlookup and other excel formula, they might not know how to use/ might accidentally delete certain stuff

Comment: That's exactly what I was suggesting - use VBA to do that.

Comment: @CDP1802 thank you for the answer! I have a few questions to ask about the code, but the comment section has limited characters and I couldn't fir them all in, I'm sorry I'm new at this, but are we allowed to continue to ask in this page?

Answer (score 0):

Define a Function to search for the products and group.

```vb
' demo
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     MsgBox StandardTime(ListBox1.Value) ' products listbox
End Sub

Private Function StandardTime(s As String) As Variant
    
    Const ROW_GRP = 3
    Const COL_GRP = "F"
       
    Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, fnd As Range, grp As String
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 2")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1") ' group table
    
    ' search group table
    Set fnd = tbl.DataBodyRange.Find(s, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Len(s) = 0 Or fnd Is Nothing Then
        StandardTime = "#N/A"
    Else
        grp = ws.Cells(ROW_GRP, fnd.Column).Value2
        ' search group time table
        Set fnd = ws.Columns(COL_GRP).Find(grp, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If fnd Is Nothing Then
            StandardTime = "#N/A"
        Else
            StandardTime = fnd.Offset(, 1)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```